# Error : nvDTE100.Solution4..GetProjectTemplate Microsoft.CrmDeveloperTools

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am working with VS 2010 to create a plugin for dynamics crm online. Everything was fine until today when I want to create a new template for dynamics crm, I get the next error :

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The System cannot find the file
>   specified (Exception from HRESULT:0x80070002) at
>   EnvDTE100.Solution4.GetProjectTemplate(String TemplateName, String
>   Language) at
>   Microsoft.CrmDeveloperTools.TemplateExtensions.CRMTemplateExtension.RunFinished()

I have re installed the toolkit  but the same error.
Pleased any idea about the source of this problem. Thanks in advance,